# Which logback configuration will be used for modules?

Tags: java, web-applications, war, logback

i have a web project consisting of modules where each modules has its own logback.xml . Now war module has also its logback.xml
(under `explodedDirectory > WEB-INF > Classes`)

My question is which(war logback or module logback) logback configuration will be used actually for modules ?  Will war logback override module configuration also ?